# How to get distinct values as a fraction map in Scala?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark

I want to do stratified sampling on my dataframe in Scala. My dataframe has only one column and I want to form a fraction map for it. I am able to do it in pyspark but it gives me error in Scala. Here is what I tried in Scala:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lit}
val fractions = pqdf.select("vin").distinct().withColumn("fraction", lit(0.001)).rdd.collect().toMap
```

It errors out saying:

`Error:(25, 100) Cannot prove that org.apache.spark.sql.Row <:< (T, U).
    val fractions = pqdf.select("vin").distinct().withColumn("fraction", lit(0.001)).rdd.collect().toMap`

How do I resolve it? I want to use the fraction map created above in `.samplyBy` method as one of the parameters

`val sampled_df = pqdf.stat.sampleBy("vin", fractions, 10L)`

This is what I tried in pyspark which works:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
fractions = df.select("VIN").distinct().withColumn("fraction", lit(0.001)).rdd.collectAsMap()
# fractions
sampled_df = df.stat.sampleBy("VIN", fractions, 10)
```

I am not sure how do I achieve same thing in Scala.

Answer (score 0):

It gives you an error because `DataFrame.rdd` returns `RDD[Row]`. To make it work you need something that is convertible to `Map`, for example (if you want `Map[String, Double]`):

```
df.select("VIN").distinct()
  .select($"VIN".cast("string"))
  .withColumn("fraction", lit(0.001))
  .as[(String, Double)]
  .rdd
  .collectAsMap()
```

or

```
df.select("VIN").distinct()
  .withColumn("fraction", lit(0.001))
  .rdd
  .map { case Row(vin, fraction: Double) => (vin.toString, fraction) }
  .collectAsMap()
```

Comment: makes sense. Let me try it out at my end. Thanks much!

Comment: it gives type mismatch error: `Error:(32, 32) overloaded method value sampleBy with alternatives:
  [T](col: String, fractions: java.util.Map[T,java.lang.Double], seed: Long)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  [T](col: String, fractions: scala.collection.immutable.Map[T,scala.Double], seed: Long)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 cannot be applied to (String, scala.collection.Map[String,scala.Double], Long)
    val sampled_df = pqdf.stat.sampleBy("vin", fractions, 10L)`